# Missing assembely reference error after adding Facebook.dll using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on login with Facebook in my app using c# asp.net.I added `facebook.dll` inside Reference section but it is still showing the following error.

> Error:

```
The type of namespace name FacebookAPI does not exist in namespace Facebook.
```

Errors are coming the below line of my code.

```
Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(GetAccessToken());
```

Please let me to know Is this version mismatch or what ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't see this `FacebookAPI` class in SDK reference. Maybe you are looking for some other class:

```
FacebookClient client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(GetAccessToken());
```

Are you sure you are referring to the latest SDK documentation?

Comment: check [this](https://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/) link.

Comment: @satya - you are referring to the post, which is 5 years old. Take a look into http://facebooksdk.net/docs/reference/SDK/Facebook.FacebookClient.html and you will see that `FacebookAPI` is now `FacebookClient` class.

Comment: @ Kamo - Yes you are right.Can you recommend me any good reference link which will help me for my requirement.My requirement is user will login via facebook and get into next page and in that page user can access facebook profile info like picture,email etc...

Comment: @satya - I already did :) You can go to the link I provided in my previous comment. The `FacebookClient` class is similar to the old `FacebookAPI` class so you can compare them.

Comment: Here one name space error .can you make this correct ?  `JSONObject me = client.Get("/me");`.Error is in JSONObject .

Comment: @satya - I believe you should mark this answer as correct and post a new question with problem you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83838/discussion-between-satya-and-kamo).